# how to validate date in date picker in iphone?

Tags: iphone

i am working on a project where i am getting date value from date-picker view. I want to check for the date so that it should not enter the date prior to today's date...
plz help me with that...
thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***In Objective-C***

Set the date picker's minimumDate property:

`datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];`

***In*** ***Swift 4.x***,

```
datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
```

(Where datePicker is a reference to your UIDatePicker )